Caching npm packages in docker
Hey I'm a newbie to both docker and node . I was trying to dockerize a simple node api .
Here's my docker file:
WORKDIR app
EXPOSE 3000
ENV NODE_ENV=production
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN \
    --mount=type=cache,target=~/.npm\
    npm ci --only-production
USER node
COPY --chown=node:node /src .
CMD [ "npm" , "run" , "dev"]

My doubts and questions , have arised , when i tried to add the cache mount , as far as i know
i need to find where npm caches its packages so i can mount my cache to that location in order for npm to be able to find them so it doesn't redownload them . At first the user is the root so i'll mount the cache to the /root/.npm (~ here will be the root home) but then when i switch to the node user and run npm run won't it be unable to find the cached dependencies because the home has changed (it will become /home/node).
whenever i switch users for security purposes i really get confused about these kind of things , so any clarification will be appreciated.

A RUN --mount option only applies to the specific RUN command it's on.  Once that RUN command is finished, the mount is removed.
That means you only need to have the correct mount path for whatever directory context is correct when you're running the command.  If the home directory is /root when you run that one command, then it's correct to hard-code
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.npm \
    npm ci --only-production

When you go to run the application, it will use the local node_modules directory and it won't look at this cache directory at all.
(It is correct for node_modules to be owned by root, with files generally world-readable but not world-writable.  I might similarly remove the COPY --chown option to apply the same permissions to your source code, preventing it from getting accidentally overwritten.)

Thank you , u cleared a lot of things , but can you explain your last point(preventing it from getting accidentally overwritten) because i couldn't imagine a scenario or a concrete example to illustrate it , a clarification would be extremely helpful since m trying to imporve and optimize my docker files in every possible aspect
And is it a good idea to change the ownership of the node_modules also ?

Your application shouldn't overwrite its own files, but bugs (and security exploits) do happen.  If the source code and library files are owned by root then they can't accidentally be overwritten.  I'd avoid chowning those files to a non-root user.
